# Normalization of product of matrix and vector

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $\hat{\mathbf{v}}=\frac{\mathbf{v}}{||v||}$, $\hat{\mathbf{M}}=\frac{1}{\det \mathbf{M}}\mathbf{M}$

Do the entries of $\mathbf{\hat{M}\hat{v}}$ always lie between $0$ and $1$?

I can see how all the elements of $ \mathbf{\hat{v} \cdot \hat{v}} $ lie between $0$ and $1$. I'm having trouble generalizing this to the product of a normalized vector and normalized matrix.

Comment: When you say $0<v<1$ do you mean all its elements, or its magnitude? And what do you mean by $v^n$?

Comment: @NotNotLogical I can see your points, OP edited accordingly.

Comment: You should say "does the _magnitude_ of $Mv$ lie..." not "does $Mv$". Sometimes the notation $0<v<1$ is taken to mean that _all elements of the vector_ are between $0$ and $1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the matrix ($a>0$)$$A=\begin{pmatrix} a&0\\0&1/a\end{pmatrix}$$ which has $\det A=1$. Then for $v=[1,0]^T$ we have $$||Av||=\Big|\Big|[a,0]\Big|\Big|=a$$

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no. Take $M = \hat M = \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 1/2 \end{pmatrix}$ and $v = \hat v = (1 \; 0)^T$. Then $\hat M \hat v = (2 \; 0)^T$.